# MongoDB update query to unset specific array members based on the value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-update

I have an array of sub-document like below

```
    /* record 1 */
        {
                        "_id" : "462044",
                        "program" : [ 
                                {
                                    "name" : "Business Services"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "name" : "Homeland Security"
                                }, 

                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Engineering"
                                }, 

                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Computer Software"
                                }
                                ]

            }

    /* record 2 */
            {
                        "_id" : "462045",
                        "program" : [ 
                                {
                                    "name" : "Business Services"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "name" : "Homeland Security"
                                }, 

                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Engineering"
                                }, 

                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Computer Software"
                                }
                                ]

            }
```

[I want to delete array members which do not have 'title' sub-members]

How can I write mongo update query or a nodejs function to  get the following document set

```
    /* record 1 */
        {

                        "_id" : "462044",
                        "program" : [ 

                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Engineering"
                                }, 

                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Computer Software"
                                }
                                ]

        }


    /* record 2 */
        {
                        "_id" : "462045",
                        "program [
                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Engineering"
                                }, 

                                {
                                    "title" : [ 
                                        "associate"
                                    ],
                                    "name" : "Computer Software"
                                }
                                ]

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all your document structure looks very odd. Every record have a different field representing essentially same information, in your case `school1` and `school2`.

It can easily be fixed if you renamed those fields to just `school`.

Provided that you fix your document structure, you can easily eliminate desired sub documents with help of aggregation framework and plain update queries.

Example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      school: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$school.program",
          as: "prog",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$$prog.title",
                  true
                ]
              },
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(o){
  db.collection.updateOne({
    _id: o._id
  },
  {
    $set: {
      school: o.school
    }
  });
})
```

This will turn your old document to (removing all sub fields form program not containing `title`:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57371cdf81e9959ba1a5fab0"), 
    "school" : [
        {
            "title" : [
                "associate"
            ], 
            "name" : "Engineering"
        }, 
        {
            "title" : [
                "associate"
            ], 
            "name" : "Computer Software"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57371cdf81e9959ba1a5fab1"), 
    "school" : [
        {
            "title" : [
                "associate"
            ], 
            "name" : "Engineering"
        }, 
        {
            "title" : [
                "associate"
            ], 
            "name" : "Computer Software"
        }
    ]
}
```